# Applying multiple functions to single input in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a series of functions that are used to calculate dates -- ex.

```
m() # return the date of the first day of the month
s() # return the date of the first day of the season 
ly() # return the matching date for last year (not on 365 day calendar
```

)

I need to do something like the following:

```
    today <- Sys.Date() 
    monthStart <- m(today)  
    seasonStart <-s(today)  
    matchLy <- ly(today)  
    ly.monthStart <- m(ly(today))  
    ly.seasonStart  <-s(ly(today))
```

However the above seems rather clunky and non-R. Is there a one liner that can apply these functions to the input (today) and unpack to globals?

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly a one liner, this is a single statement after you create a list with your functions:

```
library(functional)
today <- Sys.Date() 
funs <- list(mStart=m, seasStart=s, matchLy=ly, 
  ly.ms=Compose(m, ly), ly.ss=Compose(s, ly))   # notice Compose
```

Now run:

```
list2env(envir=globalenv(), lapply(funs, function(x) x(today)))
```

That said, I'm not sure how much better this is than just having the block you used before.  The main problem is your desire to assign to the global environment, as that requires you to develop unique names.  If you just wanted to apply these sequence of functions to many dates and store the results in a list or data frame or some such, then this becomes much cleaner.

Comment: While it is not a requirement that the variables be accessible from the global environment -- these values are being passed as arguments to various functions. It seemed superfluous to calculate matchLy multiple times as input to multiple functions, hence globals (seems globals to be avoided as much as possible in R). I think I may just hold the variables in a list and pass them into the appropriate functions or use some *ply from plyr

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom function in the veins of:

```
map <- function(x, ...) {
  functions <- list(...)
  res <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(functions)) 
    res[[i]] <- functions[[i]](x)
  names(res) <- names(functions)
  return(res)
}
```

Then apply several functions to one piece of data:

```
res <- map(Sys.Date(), monthStart=m, 
                       seasonStart=s, 
                       matchLy=ly)
```

And push it into the invironment:

```
list2env(res, envir=globalenv())
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
library(lubridate)
today <- Sys.time()
funs <- c("day", "month", "year")
sapply(funs, do.call, list(today))
```